# Emojis on Signal app library libsignal-service-java

Tags: java

I am trying to create a chatbot for Signal messaging app using libsignal-service-java and signal-cli-0.7.4.

I can create and receive messages but when I attach emoji, the emoji are replaced with **?** when I send or receive from my chatbot.

I have tried to write the emoji code (e.g ** :wave:**) as per documentation and app, but it doesnt seem to send through to the bot.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you're setting the `$LANG` environment variable right. It should end with `.UTF-8`. When you have set this variable you can just copy and past a emoji.

Reference: https://github.com/AsamK/signal-cli/issues/297#issuecomment-613467168